# ios portrait and landscape mode

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, landscape-portrait

I have the following scenario:

From appDelegate I do:

```
firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
```

firstViewController - **needs to be only in portrait mode**

In order to accomplish this I did:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

From `firstViewController` I am **pushing another view controller** which needs to have both portrait and landscape capabilities.

The `secondViewController` acts as expected - in portait and landscape mode

**I have issues with firstViewController which is displayed in landscape mode too,** though I've restricted it to Portrait mode. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the **UINavigationController Category** with following method in your project

```
#import "UINavigationController+MyNavigation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (MyNavigation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: it s not solving my issue. My view can still rotate in landscape and portrait mode

Comment: i did comment the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: you mean commenting of shouldAutoRotate is solved your issue?

Comment: yes i did. What i realize just now is that the methods: shouldAutoriatte, shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation or supportedInterfaceOrientatin are not called. Do you know why? I have a tabBarController which contain a first viewController which should only be in portrait and than from this firstViewController i push a button which sends me to the second viewController which should be in portrait and landscape mode

Comment: It clearly says that you have not implemented the category what I answered above.